# Ubuntu 18.04 restarting by itself after shutdown

Tags: boot, grub2, shutdown, reboot, wakeonlan

I know there are already plenty questions here related to this one, but I can't find an answer which solves my problem.

I've installed a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Optiplex 9020 SFF. And now I'm trying to make WOL - Wake On Lan - working. The first step I've done was to activate WOL in BIOS and deactivate Deep Sleep. And it seems to just work as expected.

I can shutdown PC and wake it up with a magic packet (and do it an unlimited number of times).

But **if I choose to restart/reboot**, the PC will do it normally and then if I try to shut it down (with the button on the top-right of the screen (or with a `shutdown now, shutdown -H now`) **it will shutdown, wait 3 seconds, and then reboot by itself**. The only way to shut it down is to long press the hardware power button. And then it reworks as expected (with WOL) until the next reboot/restart is issued.

I've tried several things in `/etc/default/grub` like adding `acpi=force apm=power_off` or `noapic` or `reboot=a,w` followed by an `update-grub`. I've also updated my BIOS to latest version (A25). But nothing works.

I think the problem is when I trigger a `reboot`, something change somewhere and make following `shutdown` working a bit differently and cause computer to reboot by itself.

I've maybe a clue after investigating `journalctl`.
When I trigger a normal shutdown (without a reboot before):

```
sept. 07 00:57:28 barbie systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
sept. 07 00:57:28 barbie systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
sept. 07 00:57:28 barbie systemd[1]: Starting Power-Off...
sept. 07 00:57:28 barbie systemd[1]: Shutting down.
sept. 07 00:57:28 barbie kernel: printk: systemd-shutdow: 40 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
sept. 07 00:57:28 barbie systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
sept. 07 00:57:28 barbie systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
sept. 07 00:57:28 barbie systemd-journald[431]: Journal stopped
```

And when I trigger a shutdown (with a reboot before):

```
sept. 07 00:59:08 barbie systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
sept. 07 00:59:08 barbie systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
sept. 07 00:59:08 barbie systemd[1]: Starting Power-Off...
sept. 07 00:59:08 barbie systemd[1]: Shutting down.
sept. 07 00:59:08 barbie kernel: printk: systemd-shutdow: 39 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
sept. 07 00:59:08 barbie systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
sept. 07 00:59:08 barbie systemd-journald[426]: Journal stopped
```

Note the missing line: `systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...` Maybe it explains why the computer reboot by itself ?

That's all I've done so far. Your clues/ideas are welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This week I unwantedly enabled more than just magic packets to wake the PC
**this resulted in the pc constantly rebooting**
`ethtool -s enp3s0 wol g` **will only allow magic packets,** whereas
`ethtool -s enp3s0 wol pumbg` **will accept ping, arp, broadcast,...**

> if you want the setting to persisst you also need to make a service:
>   `etc/systemd/system/wol.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Configure Wake-up on LAN

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/ethtool -s enp3s0 wol g

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

this service will only be applied when you edit `/etc/netplan/youryamlfile`
to contain **wakeonlan: true**:

```
      ethernets:
          enp3s0:
                  addresses: [192.168.0.99/24]
                  gateway4: 192.168.0.1
                  wakeonlan: true
                  nameservers:
                    addresses: [192.168.0.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have UEFI Bios enabled or legacy boot mode? ^

What BIOS version are you running?

I stopped the rebooting on my system (a Dell Optiplex 9020 SFF running Ubuntu 18.04 like yours) by disabling the USB 3.0 ports *in BIOS > System configuration > USB Configuration > [untick] enable USB 3.0 ports*.

While this doesn't completely solve the issue for me (I now have 6 unusable USB 3.0 ports) it does give us an idea as to what could be causing the issue.
I would recommend having a PS2 keyboard and mouse at the ready if you decide to make this change on your system.

^ my system was running in legacy mode to start with, but I had to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 on it in order to get the graphics drivers to work, UEFI mode had to be enabled in this case, that is when the issue started for me.

My system also has BIOS version A25.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. In the end the simple solution:

- unconnected the USB hub

This was the only change and can be reproduced.
Hope it helps somewone